# how to Convert Image to Sketch-like-image using Javascript CANVAS API

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Hi so I'm trying to convert an image to sketch-like-image before uploading it to the server, the uploading part is not the problem, the conversion of image to sketch-like-image is. I failed to search a js library that will help me achieve this, and then I found this https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/sketchify-turn-any-image-into-a-pencil-sketch-with-10-lines-of-code-cf67fa4f68ce sample code in `python` then tried to recreate it using CSS only and I got it correctly using the CSS code below

```
filter: grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px);
mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;
```

Then after that I tried to recreate it in Vanilla Javascript using CANVAS API because I needed the image to be uploaded in the server that looks like a sketch-like-image, but got stuck in the process **here are the stages of the conversion I'm doing see image below** [image]

I got stuck in the stage 4, I can't proceed with the stage 5, which is `globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge';` when color-dodge applied to CANVAS API, to remove the blur and make it look like an sketch-image

- stage 1 is the raw image
- stage 2 is `grayscale(100%)` working in javascript CANVAS API
- stage 3 is `invert(100%)` working in javascript CANVAS API
- stage 4 is `blur(5px)` working in javascript CANVAS API
- stage 5 `globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge'` which is equivalent of CSS' `mix-blend-mode: color-dodge;` I think? I'm not sure but I assumed it is. **not working** in javascript CANVAS API

and here's my Javascript code below

```
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.filter = 'grayscale(100%) invert(100%) blur(5px)'; // stages 2,3,4 is working
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge'; // stage 5 not working
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Ok so I think that's a lot so here's a snippet of it for you guys to test it out. https://codepen.io/ohyeahhu/pen/MWQRweP

also if you guys know a JS library or tools that might help me achieve this feat, I'm very open to any suggestions.

**note: only in javascript or any js library**

Comment: I suspect you need to overlay the original image with the stage-4 output and do the 'color-dodge'. That's how it works with Photoshop modification layers.

Comment: @RenevanderLende by "overlay the original image with the stage-4 output" you mean I need to merge/combine the original image to the stage-4 output and then use the `globalCompositeOperation='color-dodge'` to it right? did I understood that correctly?

Comment: hey @RenevanderLende thanks It works, but I still have some modifications to do, I guess I never think of that solution cause I always assumed that It only needs one image like how I did it on the CSS, but yeah I need to merge image for the `globalCompositeOperation` to works. I will post the answer soon as I have converted it to the sketch like image, thanks bro!

Comment: Glad I could help. I was thinking of some  `position: relative` parent with the original image and a stack of all kinds of `position: absolute` child elements on top of it (like PS modification layers) using `mix-blend-mode`. Did that a few years back, works as advertised, no JS required. Try a 'soft-light' layer with B/W colors. A little black darkens, a little white lightens. Perfect for under/overexposed areas in photos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting it here for others, the solution to this is I need to generate a black & white and blur canvas/img separately and then merge them using CANVAS API.

So to summarize the code below, I created 2 function. `filter` and `generateSketch`, `filter` purpose is to add filter to the canvas element and `generateSketch` is to merge two canvas (black & white and blur) into one to create a sketch like image.

HTML

```
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h1 class="text-center">Converted using JAVASCRIPT</h1>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/Wb5CcD8L/corgi2.jpg" id="raw-img" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6" id="result">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Javascript

```
  window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async (event) => {
    // add filters to canvas element
    const filter = (bmp, filters="") => {
      let canvas = Object.assign(document.createElement('canvas'), { width: bmp.width, height: bmp.height });
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.filter = filters;
      ctx.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
      return canvas;
    }
    // merge two canvas into one to generate sketch like image
    const generateSketch = (bnw, blur) => {
      let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
      canvas.width = bnw.width;
      canvas.height = bnw.height;
      canvas.__skipFilterPatch = true; // davidenke/context-filter-polyfill fix for safari ios devices
      let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(bnw, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge';
      ctx.drawImage(blur, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      return canvas;
    }
    let rawImg = document.getElementById('raw-img');
    // first: step create bitmap from the `rawImg`
    let bmp = await createImageBitmap(rawImg);
    // second: generate a black & white and blur canvas using filter()
    let bnw = filter(bmp, "grayscale(1)");
    let blur = filter(bmp, "grayscale(1) invert(1) blur(5px)");
    // third: merge / combine `bnw` and `blur` canvas
    let sketchImg = generateSketch(bnw, blur);
    // display output
    let resultDiv = document.getElementById('result');
    resultDiv.prepend(sketchImg);
  });
```

you can check it on my codepen for the working sample https://codepen.io/ohyeahhu/pen/MWQRweP.

note: I also used https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill to fix the compatibility issue on Safari IOS devices.

This is also related to this [CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation is not working on safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73059883/canvasrenderingcontext2d-globalcompositeoperation-is-not-working-on-safari/73061629#73061629)