# CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation is not working on safari

Tags: javascript, canvas, safari

I'm not sure if this `CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation` is not really working or working in safari, but I've tested it.

I'm working on a Convert Image to Sketch Image feature using Javascript, and this implementation involves `CANVAS API` or  `CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation` to be exact.

To explain the flow, I'm generating two images using the image selected, 1 black and white image, and 1 black and white a with blurred image, and then after, that I'm using this `merge` function to merge/combine them to have Sketch-drew-image. Check this https://codepen.io/ohyeahhu/pen/RwMVjym, if you are using Chrome of course it will work, but if you are using safari browser the Sketch Image will not work.

The script `filter` function below is how I convert/generate an Image to a black and white and blurred using `CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter` in CANVAS API.

Now I know that the `CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter` doesn't have any support from the safari browser but I've solved that part by using https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill thanks to this beautiful suggestion https://stackoverflow.com/a/65843002/17678769

```
const filter = function(img, filter) {
   let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = img.width;
   canvas.height = img.height;
   let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.filter = filter;
   ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
   return canvas;
}
```

The script below is the one I'm using to create a sketch-like-image. Now the `ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge';` line of code supposed to make the image like a Sketch-drew-image but somehow in Safari browsers mobile devices or mac, it is not working.

```
const merge = function(front, overlay) {
   let canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
   canvas.width = front.width;
   canvas.height = front.height;
   let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'color-dodge';
   ctx.drawImage(front, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   ctx.drawImage(overlay, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
   let img = document.createElement('img');
   img.src = canvas.toDataURL();
   return img;
}
```

I've read the MDN documentation of `CanvasRenderingContext2D.globalCompositeOperation` and it says that safari browsers fully supports it.

If that's the case, then I do not know where did I go wrong on this implementation, Did I made a mistake in the implementation? I'm really stuck in this for a day, is there any alternative or solution to this issue/problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Safari does support `globalCompositeOperation` (gCO), they even do have the biggest list of modes they support among all three main browsers <sub>(though I found a rendering bug)</sub>.

The problem lies in your filter polyfill. It probably messed up somewhere when monkeypatching the various methods of the context and broke the gCO ([it also broke `clearRect`](https://github.com/davidenke/context-filter-polyfill/issues/10)).
Seeing how there is no activity on the project I'm not sure you'll be able to have it fixed, but a simple workaround is to let the polyfill know it shouldn't be called on that canvas by setting the `__skipFilterPatch` property to true on your canvas:

```js
function createCanvas({width, height}) {
  return Object.assign(document.createElement("canvas"), { width, height });
}
function filter(source, filters) {  
  const canvas = createCanvas(source);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.filter = filters;
  ctx.drawImage(source, 0, 0);
  return canvas;
}
(async() => {
  const blob = await fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/20141025_Shockwave_Truck_Alliance_Air_Show_2014-3.jpg/640px-20141025_Shockwave_Truck_Alliance_Air_Show_2014-3.jpg").then(resp => resp.blob());
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  const gray = filter(bmp, "grayscale(1)");
  const blur = filter(bmp, "grayscale(1) invert(1) blur(5px)");
  const canvas = createCanvas(bmp);
  canvas.__skipFilterPatch = true; // the magic
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.drawImage(gray, 0, 0);
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "color-dodge";
  ctx.drawImage(blur, 0, 0);
  document.body.append(canvas);
 })().catch(console.error);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/context-filter-polyfill@0.2.4/dist/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: works like a charm! thank you @kaiido, I've applied your sample snippet to my work and it is indeed working in safari browsers, you're a life saver, thank you!